# When to use Action over ActionListener

Tags: java, interface, action, actionlistener

The Java API says,

> "The Action interface provides a useful extension to the ActionListener interface in cases where the same functionality may be accessed by several controls."

I can do the same with custom inner class listeners. What am I missing? 
I do see some of the benefits of Action (icons, descriptions, enabled state).

Comment: "I do see some of the benefits of `Action` (icons, descriptions, enabled state)." - so, what other benefits do you need? The idea behind actions is that you can reuse the same object for e.g. a toolbar button and a menu item that does the same. If it's a toggle button, the state will automatically synchronise between all the UI elements that represent it. An `Action` is a "rich" model object that can be thought to contain an action listener.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, I prefer `Action` over `ActionListener` in almost most circumstances.

Apart from providing a self contained, reusable concept that can be applied to buttons and key bindings, I find it can produce cleaner code.

I know a lot people prefer to use either inner classes or very large `actionPeformed` statements with n depths of `if-else` statements, but for me `Action` provides an API which is more easily maintained and updatable,

I still use `ActionListener` in situations where I don't need to display the object that is triggering the `actionPerformed` event, such as the Swing `Timer` for example

For me, where you want to maintain a self contained unit of work, which needs to be displayed to the user and/or want to design a series of abstract actionable elements, `Action` is the preferred method